# Entity reference or viewfield for Drupal8: How to embedd views output in my node?

Tags: views, entities

In Drupal 7 it was possible to include into one node (/node/x/edit) the following lines

```
Label 1
[view:adresses=block_1=argument1]
Label 2
[view:adresses=block_1=argument2]
Label 3
[view:adresses=block_1=argument3]
```

Result: Output of the view depending on the argument.

I need the same solution in Drupal 8!
How can I realize this?

Maybe entitity reference can solve this but I am able to use entity reference in Drupal 7 but in Drupal 8 this does not work (or I don't know how).

In Drupal 7 there are other modules like "View reference", "Viewfield" ... to solve this in a similar way.

**But how can I solve this in Drupal 8?**
The output (e.g. block) of a view should be displayed in the content of one specific node.

How can I create a node field with a reference to my adresses view output?
Thank you.

Comment: The only reason that was possible was via token and extended token integrations to allow you to insert a token into a WYSIWYG. That certainly wasn't core behavior on its own. Reference fields are now preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself:

I use the modules [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and [Twig input filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig)

to solve the problem above in Drupal 8. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args); // remove $name
  if (count($args)) {
    array_shift($args); // remove $display_id
  }

  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return $view->preview($display_id, $args);
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x

Comment: This is a Drupal 7 function, I need a solution für Drupal 8 as you can see above. I do not want to write code for this because in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 this was not necessary.

Comment: It exists in Drupal 8. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.2.x